# How to check if a tkinter window is visible?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way to check if a Windows user is seeing a tkinter Window?
e.g. when I click on Chrome or any other application, it opens in front of all other applications, including my tkinter application. Is there a way to check if the user can see the tkinter application?

Images to illustrate the case:

-->
[Here I can see both my tkinter application and Chrome window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uctqI.jpg)

--> [If I then click anywhere inside the Chrome window, it hides my tkinter application, I'm looking for a way to check that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubVWV.jpg)

As you can see, I don't think it is minimizing the Tkinter Application, just hiding it. Is there a way to check for this hide? (When I try the Map/Unmap, winfo_ismapped, it cannot detect the hiding, it still returns to me that the window is mapped even though I can't see it)

Comment: What is the purpose of this information, why do you need to know this?

Comment: @DanyaK my application is focused on monitoring the time I'm spending studying. When I hide the application (probably because I clicked somewhere else to watch a youtube or other distractions), I'd like to set it to automatically stop counting the overall study time.

Comment: If you want your application to always be on top of other windows then try changing window attributes like this `root.attributes('-topmost', 1)`. That way you won't need to monitor anything.

Comment: Will it be enough to check if the window is focused?

Answer (score 0):

To check if a tkinter window is visible, check your Python interpreter. Depending on your operating system, it is called one of two things, either:
A: "Python 3.12 (64-Bit)"
OR
B: "Python 3.12 (32-Bit)"

Please note, it may not be 3.12, but it should be. The icon looks like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1bET.jpg)

If there are any windows open, hover over or right-click on the icon. Check for a window preview. If there is none, click on them until you find the right one. If there is no active window of your program, the user is unable to see the window.

Hope this helps!